# What is this error Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. > -1

Tags: android, android-studio

I run through pasted colors.xml styles.xml fonts Roboto . However after all run-through I face `

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
 -1
```

How can I fix this issue that the project won't compile ?

Comment: Try refreshing your project then rerun your app.

Comment: Hi UserSharma, I am still facing the same error

Comment: post that complete error and edit your question

Comment: Hi MinnuKaAnae, that is the complete error

Comment: can you post your project path, max path length is 255 characters

Comment: Hi MinnuJaAnae, it wasn't too long for 255 characters

Comment: which gradle version you are using?

Comment: I am using gradle 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your new resource files that you have pasted, there may be two resource with the same name in any different module.